# Error in overloading operator *

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've a little problem with the overloading of an operator. I've a class named AtmospheridData, in which I define the operator *.

In the header I define this method inside the class:

```
//! Operator * (scalar)
AtmosphericData operator*(const qreal& qrMult) const;
```

and the definition, in the .cpp file, is the following:

```
AtmosphericData AtmosphericData::operator*(const qreal& qrMult) const
{
    AtmosphericData xResult;

    xResult.m_qrTemperature        = this->m_qrTemperature * qrMult;
    xResult.m_qrPressure           = this->m_qrPressure * qrMult;
    xResult.m_qrDensity            = this->m_qrDensity * qrMult;
    xResult.m_qrAbsoluteHumidity   = this->m_qrAbsoluteHumidity * qrMult;
    xResult.m_qrVisibility         = this->m_qrVisibility * qrMult;
    xResult.m_qrPrecipitationIndex = this->m_qrPrecipitationIndex * qrMult;
    xResult.m_xWind.qrNS           = this->m_xWind.qrNS * qrMult;
    xResult.m_xWind.qrEW           = this->m_xWind.qrEW * qrMult;
    xResult.m_xWind.qrVert         = this->m_xWind.qrVert * qrMult;

     xResult.m_xPrecipitationType = this->m_xPrecipitationType;

     return xResult;
}
```

Then, I use the class in the following expression:

```
AtmosphericData c2;
AtmosphericData t1;
AtmosphericData t2;
AtmosphericData y0;
AtmosphericData y1;
qreal           hx;

/* other code */

c2 = - (3 * (y0 - y1) + (hx * ((2 * t1) + t2))) / (hx * hx);
```

When I compile (using qmake-gcc under linux) I obtain the following error

```
error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘3 * AtmosphericData::operator-(const AtmosphericData&) const(((const AtmosphericData&)((const AtmosphericData*)(& y1))))’
```

I seems that I'm doing something wrong with the operator * declaration, but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Can anyone tell me how I can correct this error?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: since you are declaring the operator in the class definition, are you sure you made it public?

Comment: Yes, but now I've added the multiplication override with exchanged order between the qreal argument and the atmosphericdata one and it seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

Arithmetic operators in C++ are not automatically commutative, thus your operator kicks in only when you do `AtmosphericData * qreal`, but not when the ordering of the types is the opposite (which is what happens in the `3 * (y0 - y1)` expression).

You have to write also an `operator*` to handle the `qreal * AtmosphericData` case, which must be written as a free function because the type of the left hand operand is not of the type of your class.

```
inline AtmosphericData operator*(const qreal& lhs, const AtmosphericData & rhs)
{
    // Just forward to the other operator (this works because I swapped the operands)
    return rhs * lhs;
}
```

---

By the way, IMHO to implement the mathematical operators you should follow the usual pattern of implementing first the assigning-versions (`*=`), and then call them from the "normal" (`*`) version; see the [operator overloading FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719) for more details.

Comment: Really thanks for the link. I'll read the FAQ as soon as possible.

Comment: @jepessen: C++ is a big and complicated language, we are all noobs in some of its aspects :) By the way, if my answer solved your problem you can consider accepting if (the big tick under the votes count).

Answer (score 0):

If you write :

```
c2 = - ((y0 - y1) * 3 + (hx * ((t1 * 2 ) + t2))) / (hx * hx);
```

instead of

```
c2 = - (3 * (y0 - y1) + (hx * ((2 * t1) + t2))) / (hx * hx);
```

then it should work. Because the definition of `operator*` in your code requires that the object of type `AtmosphericData` should be on the left side of `*`. That is, `3 * y` wouldn't work, but `y*3` would work where `y` is an object of type `AtmosphericData`.

If you want `3*y` to work as well, then define a **non-member** function as:

```
AtmosphericData operator*(const qreal &r, const AtmosphericData& a)
{
   return d*r;//call the other overloaded, or calculate the value here if you wish!
}
```

I would suggest you to define other function as non-member function as well. And if needs to access private or protected members, then make it `friend`. Otherwise, non-member non-friend should your first choice.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to multiply a AtmostphereicData by an int (`3*blah` and `2*blah`), an operation which you don't appear to have defined.

Ddefine an operator which takes a left hand side of int and right-hand side of AtmosphereicData.

Answer (score 0):

You have  defined an `operator *` whose first argument is AtmosphericData and the second is a number. But NOT vice versa.

You should define the other operator as well (as a nonmember)

```
AtmosphericData operator * (qreal num, const AtmosphericData& ad )
{
    return ad*num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the operator inside the class, it will only work if you use your class on the *left*. To use your class on the right you need to also overload the operator as a free function:

```
AtmosphericData operator*(const qreal& qrMult, const AtmosphericData& data);
```

You could also use [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) and get all this for free with `operator*=`.

```
class AtmosphericData : boost::multipliable<AtmosphericData, qreal> 
{

   // blah

public:
    AtmosphericData& operator*=(const qreal& qrMult) {
        // blah blah
        return *this;
    }
    // by inheriting from boost::multipliable, this gives you both operator* for free
}
```